# Can I use pivot_longer to make a series of dichotomous variable?

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data set looks roughly like below. Is there a way to use `pivot_longer()` to turn a column variable into a series of dichotomous variables, 1 indicating the row has that value, 0 indicating that it does not?

This is not right, but it's my attempt. Desired output follows at the end.

```
library(tidyverse)
election<-sample(seq(1965,2000, by=5),replace=T, size=100)
var1<-sample(c('red', 'blue'), replace=T, size=100)
var2<-sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=100)
var3<-sample(c('up', 'down'), replace=T, size=100)             
df<-data.frame(election, var1, var2, var3)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_from=election, values_from=election)
```

| vaar1 | var2 | var3 | 1965 | 1970 | 1975 | 1980 | 1985 | 1990 | 1995 | 2000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 0 | up | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = var1:var3, 
              names_from = election, 
              values_from = election, 
              values_fn = \(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0),
              values_fill = 0L,
              names_sort = T)
```

If your `R` version is < 4.1.0 then replace `\(x)` with `function(x)`.

**Output**

```
 var1   var2 var3  `1965` `1970` `1975` `1980` `1985` `1990` `1995` `2000`
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 red       1 down       1      1      1      1      0      1      0      1
2 red       0 down       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
3 red       1 up         1      1      0      1      1      0      1      1
4 blue      0 down       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
5 blue      1 down       0      1      1      1      1      0      1      0
6 blue      1 up         1      0      0      0      1      1      1      1
7 blue      0 up         1      1      0      1      1      0      0      1
8 red       0 up         0      0      1      0      0      1      0      1
```

---

**How it works**

To help understand how this works, focus on what will become one row in the pivoted dataframe:

```
df %>% filter(var1 == "red", var2 == 1, var3 == "down") %>% arrange(election)
   election var1 var2 var3
1      1965  red    1 down
2      1965  red    1 down
3      1970  red    1 down
4      1975  red    1 down
5      1980  red    1 down
6      1990  red    1 down
7      1990  red    1 down
8      2000  red    1 down
9      2000  red    1 down
10     2000  red    1 down
11     2000  red    1 down
```

1. It's clear that the `id_cols` are `var1:var3` e.g. we don't want to pivot those. So our focus is on the column `election`.
2. It's also clear you want `election` to be the column names, hence `names_from = election`, but we also want to do something with the *values* of `election` as well when we pivot.
3. Taking a look at the sample dataframe where `var1 == "red", var2 == 1, var3 == "down"` the value in election is not *uniquely* identified by `var1:var3`. So for row `var1 == "red", var2 == 1, var3 == "down"` and column `` `1965` `` we have two values in this case: `c(1965, 1965)` and `pivot_wider` is unsure what to do with these values (by default it will store them as a `list` object).
4. So we provide instructions about what to do in this instance, `pivot_wider` applies the function that we pass to `values_fn`. In the example, this will resolve to `as.integer(length(c(1965,1965)) > 0)` and the output becomes `1` in this case. Even where it's uniquely identified, this function will still work:

```
as.integer(length(c(1980)) > 0)
[1] 1
```

Since we're simply testing if there is a value and returning `1` if there is.

5. Lastly, not every `election` column has a value for `var1:var3`. For this example, there is no `1985`. By default, `pivot_wider` will fill that value with `NA`. We provide instruction to fill it with the integer `0L` with the `values_fill` argument. Try running it with this argument commented out and it should be clear.

Comment: You can use the `names_sort` argument (`names_sort = TRUE`)  if you want to improve the output column order. :)

Comment: And if the R version is 4.1 or above, you can replace `%>%`with `|>` ;-)

Comment: @tpetzoldt thanks for the comment -- though the `%>%` pipe is imported with the library `tidyr`.

Comment: Of course ;-) it was just for curiosity, since I wonder what will happen with the magritter `%>%` in the future, since R has now a native pipe built-in. But this is of surely of topic here.

Comment: My own plan is to stick with %>% ; too much change!!!!

Comment: this is amazing, but can you walk me through the values_fn and the values_fill arguments?

Comment: @spindoctor I've updated my answer with a **How it works** section.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dcast` from `data.table` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ... ~ election,  value.var = 'election', \(x) +(length(x) > 0))
```

-output

```
    var1 var2 var3 1965 1970 1975 1980 1985 1990 1995 2000
1: blue    0 down    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
2: blue    0   up    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1
3: blue    1 down    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1
4: blue    1   up    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
5:  red    0 down    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1
6:  red    0   up    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
7:  red    1 down    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1
8:  red    1   up    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```